# Set a line(edge) as body for almost 0 thickness box2d iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am trying to add a line as box2d body for almost 0 or 1 pixel thickness.I tried to use lot of methods like setasedge,setasbox but i couldn't get it.

```
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2([self x:256],[self y:0]), b2Vec2([self x:256],[self y:64]));

    //groundBox.SetAsBox(0.01, 1.11, b2Vec2([self x:256],[self y:0]), 0.1);

    groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox,0.1f);
```

and for b2EdgeShape is showing that it doesn't exist.I included  as  found in box2d reference api. Could you suggest me any idea to draw a line with almost null thickness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know cocos2D itself, but I'm sure **the physics and the display are dissociated**. You might want to try to find where cocos2D manage the display and verify **if your graphic card** is able to display a thin line (eg. the thinner for me is 0.4) :

```
GLfloat lWidth[2];
glGetFloatv(GL_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, lWidth);
```

By the way, if your cocos2D supports Box2D 2.2, you could try a chain object instead of an edge, with loop enabled or not.